# Is a response and status code required even when the client side doesn't care about the response?

Tags: httpresponse, http-status-codes

I'm trying to design an endpoint that just does some loggings for the client-side applications. The implementation is simple, just log the events that the client send to some platforms. (We don't want the mobile app to integrate with the platforms directly) If the client doesn't care about the response and won't handle the response either, is there a need for the server to send back the 200 all the time? Or is it okay to just return nothing?
I can't seem to find any similar use cases. Maybe giving a status code is always a good practice?

I'm using sprint boot and the controller allows the return type of void.

Comment: If you want to "speak" HTTP you have to return the HTTP status code defined by the protocol. However, you don't need to "speak" HTTP at all. You can use a simple proprietary socket connection.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your product and you're not beholden to any other API expectations or other miscellaneous requirements, you can implement whatever behavior you'd like.

That said I can understand wanting to stick to best practices. In general if the response is going to be empty, a simple HTTP status code of 204 is typically the best option to conform to standard HTTP status codes.